# 'GRU' object has no attribute '_flat_weights_names'

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, gru

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Temp\ipykernel_6580\3729707838.py in <module>
      9                                   num_layers, dropout)
     10 net = d2l.EncoderDecoder(encoder, decoder)
---> 11 d2l.train_seq2seq(net, train_iter, lr, num_epochs, tgt_vocab, device)
     12 
     13 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\d2l\torch.py in train_seq2seq(net, data_iter, lr, num_epochs, tgt_vocab, device)
   1032                 if "weight" in param:
   1033                     nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m._parameters[param])
-> 1034     net.apply(xavier_init_weights)
   1035     net.to(device)
   1036     optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in apply(self, fn)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in apply(self, fn)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in apply(self, fn)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\d2l\torch.py in xavier_init_weights(m)
   1029             nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight)
   1030         if type(m) == nn.GRU:
-> 1031             for param in m._flat_weights_names:
   1032                 if "weight" in param:
   1033                     nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m._parameters[param])

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __getattr__(self, name)
```

AttributeError: 'GRU' object has no attribute '_flat_weights_names'

AttributeError: 'GRU' object has no attribute '_flat_weights_names'
how to fix ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`type(m) == nn.GRU`
try
`isinstance(m, nn.GRU)`

Comment: How do you know that that's the issue if OP didn't provide any code?

Comment: From the log I see 5 lines of code,  
so may be try my solution. But I'm not sure that the issue comes from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems coming from the initialisation of GRU.
May be learn how to initalise an `nn.GRU`:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/initializing-rnn-gru-and-lstm-correctly/23605